# Asynchronous URL connection objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I created an asynchronous URL connection to call a web service using HTTP POST method. after I am pinging the web i set an NSTimerInterval in the completion handler. my problem is when I'm trying to display the time on the view controller it is not doing promptly. I know block is stored in the heap and gets executed later on anytime and probably that's why i'm not getting prompt answer. I was wondering is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

my code:

```
__block NSDate *start= [NSDate date];
   __block NSDate *end;
__block double miliseconds;
__block NSTimeInterval time;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

     if([data length]==0 && error==nil){

         end=[NSDate date];
        time=[end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
      NSLog(@"Successfully Pinged");
         miliseconds = time;

  // calling a method to display ping time 

         [self label:miliseconds];

     }

-(void) label:(double) mili{
    double miliseconds=mili*1000;

    self.timeDisplay.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %.3f ms", miliseconds];
```

Comment: What do you mean by a delay? The completionBlock is first executed when the request is done. Also you could experience a "delay" if the queue is not the mainQueue. Use [NSOperationQueue mainQueue].

Comment: thank you so much. I did it with creating a new queue and then used main queue